# Reinstall windows8 and install original Windows 8 laptop ASUS K55v From Hidden or Recovery Partition

Tags: windows-8, asus-laptop, partition-recovery

One of my friends laptop the explorer.exe file is damaged and I could not fix it ,now i want to change or reinstall windows.

now I 'm currently using the original Windows 8 ,I want to re-install Windows8 so I do not know How can I install windows by hide partition in laptop ,Or hidden partition

Im not sure that this laptop has hidden recovery partition for reinsalling windows8 or not ?!
Now when i want to go to systems boot option, None of : DEL ,f8, f9, f10, f11, f12, Tab ,buttons doesn't enter to boot option!!!!

i read that i most hold F9 during booting, but none of this buttons doesnt make any difference

please tell me how can i reinstall original widows 8 from hidden partition so that other partitions(D) Will NOT be Format ! and my hidden partition Will NOT be Format too!

Comment: Windows 8 has a built-in "Reset" feature.  I suggest you do that.  Most Windows 8 OEM products didn't come with an actual recovery partition for this reason.  If the laptop does have one, then what the recovery partition does is fixed, your better off trying either upgrade to Windows 8.1 ( to fix the explorer problem ) or backing up the data and simply reinstall Windows 8 with an .iso disk.